# Save data from fragment to custom session

Tags: android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I am creating a project in which I am using navigation drawer and on navigation item click it opens a login page and after login it movies to my main activity. Now, I want to save my login details and all data in my custom shared preference from the fragment. After that it on app restarts and I go to navigation login items it should check if the user is already logged in then it should move to an activity otherwise it should run my login fragment

my login fragment

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    CDSMainViewModel =
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CDP_MainViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cdplogin, container, false);

    context = container.getContext();
    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    session = new Session(context);


    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        Intent itra = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Verification_Activity.class);
        startActivity(itra);
        getActivity().finish();
    }
    else{
        login_button = root.findViewById(R.id.button_click_login);
        edit1 = root.findViewById(R.id.input_username);
        edit2 = root.findViewById(R.id.input_password);
        layout_1 = root.findViewById(R.id.usnamelayout);
        layout_2 = root.findViewById(R.id.password_layout);


        login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
    }

    return root;
}

private void Login_data() {

    String URL = "http://117.240.196.238:8080/api/cdp/getAuth";
    Log.i("response", URL);
    StringRequest jsonObjRequest = new StringRequest(
        Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("response_login", response);

                parseData1(response);


            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("volley", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                showServerConnectionError();
            }
        }) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("AuthID", name);
            params.put("AuthPwd", password);

            return params;
        }

    };
    RequestQueue queue = SingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
    queue.add(jsonObjRequest);
}
private void parseData1(String response){
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        int success = json.getInt("success");
        String msg = json.getString("message");
        if(success == 1){

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            JSONArray recData = json.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < recData.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = recData.getJSONObject(i);

                String uname = name;
                String upass = password;

                String emp_id  = c.getString("emp_id");
                String empname = c.getString("EmpName");
                String office = c.getString("OfficeNameFull");
                String desig = c.getString("DesignationName");
                String mobile = c.getString("EmpMobile");
                String office_code = c.getString("OfficeCode");
                String OfficeType = c.getString("OfficeType");
                String district = c.getString("DistrictCode");
                String DistrictName = c.getString("DistrictName");
                String designationCode = c.getString("designationCode");
                String DesignationName1 = c.getString("DesignationName1");
                String DesigShortName = c.getString("DesigShortName");

                Log.i("session",district);

                //Here my loginsession is not working its not saving my data in my session..  
                Session.getInstance(getContext()).loginsession(emp_id,uname,upass,empname,office,desig,mobile,office_code,OfficeType,district,DistrictName,designationCode,DesignationName1,DesigShortName);
                //  String email = SessionManager.getInstance(context).getUserEmail();
                //   session.loginsession(emp_id,uname,upass,empname,office,desig,mobile,office_code,OfficeType,district,DistrictName,designationCode,DesignationName1,DesigShortName);

                Intent its12 = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Verification_Activity.class);

                startActivity(its12);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_right, R.anim.slide_to_left);
                getActivity().finish();
            }


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context,msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
    }
}
}
```

//Session manager class

```
package com.example.agridept.domain;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import com.example.agridept.ui.CDP_login.CDP_MainFragment;

public class Session {

    private static Session jInstance;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context context;
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";

    String emp_id1,username1,password1 ,empname1 , office1 , desig1, mobile1, office_code1, OfficeType1 , district1 ,DistrictName1 , designationCode1, DesignationName11 , DesigShortName1;


    public Session(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = preferences.edit();

    }

public void loginsession(String emp_id,String username,String password11 ,String empname ,String  office ,String  desig,String  mobile,String  office_code,String  OfficeType ,String  district ,String DistrictName ,String  designationCode,String  DesignationName1 ,String  DesigShortName){
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
    editor.putString(emp_id1,emp_id);
    editor.putString(username1,username);
    editor.putString(password1,password11);
    editor.putString(empname1,empname);
    editor.putString(office1,office);
    editor.putString(desig1,desig);
    editor.putString(mobile1,mobile);
    editor.putString(office_code1,office_code);
    editor.putString(OfficeType1,OfficeType);
    editor.putString(district1,district);
    editor.putString(DistrictName1,DistrictName);
    editor.putString(designationCode1,designationCode);
    editor.putString(DesignationName11,DesignationName1);
    editor.putString(DesigShortName1,DesigShortName);
}

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return preferences.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }


    public void logoutUser() {
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(context, CDP_MainFragment.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        // Staring Login Activity
        context.startActivity(i);
    }

    public void clearinfo() {
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

    public SharedPreferences getPreferences() {
        return preferences;
    }

    public void setPreferences(SharedPreferences preferences) {
        this.preferences = preferences;
    }

    public SharedPreferences.Editor getEditor() {
        return editor;
    }

    public void setEditor(SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
        this.editor = editor;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getPRIVATE_MODE() {
        return PRIVATE_MODE;
    }

    public void setPRIVATE_MODE(int PRIVATE_MODE) {
        this.PRIVATE_MODE = PRIVATE_MODE;
    }

    public static String getIsLogin() {
        return IS_LOGIN;
    }

    public static String getPrefName() {
        return PREF_NAME;
    }

    public String getEmp_id1() {
        return emp_id1;
    }

    public void setEmp_id1(String emp_id1) {
        this.emp_id1 = emp_id1;
    }

    public String getPassword1() {
        return password1;
    }

    public void setPassword1(String password1) {
        this.password1 = password1;
    }

    public String getEmpname1() {
        return empname1;
    }

    public void setEmpname1(String empname1) {
        this.empname1 = empname1;
    }

    public String getOffice1() {
        return office1;
    }

    public void setOffice1(String office1) {
        this.office1 = office1;
    }

    public String getDesig1() {
        return desig1;
    }

    public void setDesig1(String desig1) {
        this.desig1 = desig1;
    }

    public String getMobile1() {
        return mobile1;
    }

    public void setMobile1(String mobile1) {
        this.mobile1 = mobile1;
    }

    public String getOffice_code1() {
        return office_code1;
    }

    public void setOffice_code1(String office_code1) {
        this.office_code1 = office_code1;
    }

    public String getOfficeType1() {
        return OfficeType1;
    }

    public void setOfficeType1(String officeType1) {
        OfficeType1 = officeType1;
    }

    public String getDistrict1() {
        return district1;
    }

    public void setDistrict1(String district1) {
        this.district1 = district1;
    }

    public String getDistrictName1() {
        return DistrictName1;
    }

    public void setDistrictName1(String districtName1) {
        DistrictName1 = districtName1;
    }

    public String getDesignationCode1() {
        return designationCode1;
    }

    public void setDesignationCode1(String designationCode1) {
        this.designationCode1 = designationCode1;
    }

    public String getDesignationName11() {
        return DesignationName11;
    }

    public void setDesignationName11(String designationName11) {
        DesignationName11 = designationName11;
    }

    public String getDesigShortName1() {
        return DesigShortName1;
    }

    public void setDesigShortName1(String desigShortName1) {
        DesigShortName1 = desigShortName1;
    }

    public static synchronized Session getInstance(Context context) {
        if (jInstance != null) {
            return jInstance;
        } else {
            jInstance = new Session(context);
            return jInstance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Do you experience any problems while running the program? If yes provide the problem you are experiencing with minimal code that is diagnosed to have the problem.

Comment: my data is not saving in my session class

Comment: Your data is not saving to session class or your data is not saving to session?

Comment: yes my data is not saving in my session

Comment: I suppose it saves, but you discard it because isLoggedIn() alwais returns false. And thiis is expected because IS_LOGIN is final and always is "IsLoggedIn". E even would expect it to throw ClassCastException

Comment: sorry not able to get uh can uh explain in littel more details ?

Comment: Please use correct english language with no slangs in comments, answers and questions.

Comment: I analysed your code and commented above the possible cause of your failure. Now you should debug and confirm if that I said is true or false and post the result here in a comment.